# Adding paramaters for an onclick function inside an element

Tags: javascript, parameters

Hey guys I'm having an issue with the syntax of providing a parameter for a function that I call on an onclick event inside a div.

I can get the function open_email() to call but not when I add a parameter since the parameter I am looking to add is obtained from another form element and I'm not sure how to type it properly.

Below is my code.  Please let me know if you know how it should be written.  I'm currently getting nothing to happen unless I keep the parameters (arguments) blank.

To clarify, I need to know how to add emails[index].id as an argument for the function below that is called open_email().  What is the proper syntax? I tried :  open_email(emails[index].id) and  open_email("emails[index].id")

```
 for (index = 0; index < emails.length; index++) {
      if (emails[index].read == false) {
        element.innerHTML += '<div class="emails unread" onclick="open_email();">' + "From:" + JSON.stringify(emails[index].sender) +
          "<p class='subject'>" + "Subject: " + JSON.stringify(emails[index].subject) + "</p>" + JSON.stringify(emails[index].timestamp) + '</div>';
      } else {
        element.innerHTML += '<div class="emails">' + "From:" + JSON.stringify(emails[index].sender) +
          "<p>" + "Subject: " + JSON.stringify(emails[index].subject) + "</p>" + JSON.stringify(emails[index].timestamp) + '</div>';
      }
```

Comment: Please create a runnable example

Comment: there's too many parts to make it runnable.   All i need to know is how to do the "onclick=open_email();" part with emails[index].id  as an argument.  I can't seem to get it to work when I add an argument.

Comment: If there are too many parts for you, who wrote it, to make it runnable -- doesn't that mean it's too many parts for us, who don't know it, to make it runnable?

Comment: it doesn't need to be runnable. I just need to know how to put an argument into the "onclick=open_email();" part.  When I put emails[index].id as an argument, it doesn't do anything when I click on it.  When there's no argument, it works.  I need to pass an argument, though. And the argument is emails[index].id

Comment: sorry i'm not sure why it unformatted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to send an arrow function there. Try to click on the text "Initial Content".

I do not have your `open_email` function, so I made up one as an example.

Basically, onclick will execute `() => open_email(emailIndexId)`:

```html
<div id="text">Initial Content</div>
<script>
  textDiv = document.getElementById('text');

  const open_email = id => {
    textDiv.innerText = "Sent email to " + id;
  }

  const emailIndexId = 33;

  textDiv.onclick = () => open_email(emailIndexId) // IMPORTANT
</script>
```

Comment: i'm sorry i think my question was confusing.  how do i put emails[index].id as an argument on the div onclick event?

Comment: `myDiv.onclick = () => open_email(emails[index].id)`

Comment: what does the => do? Is there any way to just put it in the onclick attribute instead?  I don't really understand your method.

Comment: how do put the argument (emails[index].id) in the onclick attribute?

Comment: It's an arrow function, basically an equivalent of `myDiv.onclick = function(){open_email(emails[index].id)}`, but with different scoping rules. The idea is that you create a middleman function that will run your open_email function with the necessary arguments

Comment: ok that makes sense but why won't it work normally? Like why can't I just put the argument in the onclick attribute?

Comment: because it expects a function which takes an argument (event), and you cannot change that, so you provide onclick with your own function that ignores the event and runs another function with necessary arguments

Comment: ok one last comment: what does the textDiv.onclick = () = >  mean?  Why the parenthesis?

Comment: Empty parenthesis is an empty list of arguments. Here is a basic information about arrow functions - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#:~:text=An%20arrow%20function%20expression%20is,be%20used%20in%20all%20situations.

Comment: yes but i don't want an empty list of arguments.  I want an argument. Which you add later in the line.

Comment: why can't i just do myDiv.onclick(emails[index].id)?  I don't get the point of the = () => adding to it.  Doesn't seem necessary. I have the function defined outside of this function.

Comment: Try to do it and look what happens. You need to supply a function to the onclick, it needs to run something, it cannot run a string or number (whatever is your id)

Comment: ok i got you so it's basically the new syntax for javascript event handling?  OK looks weird but I'll get used to it thanks

Comment: it's not a new syntax, it was like that for many years :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223726/discussion-between-card51short-and-ivand).